# Help normalising and taking the inverse Fourier transform of this wavefunction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, fourier-transform, normalization

**Normalising**

Consider the wavefunction $$\psi(x,0)=Ne^{-\frac{|x|}{\lambda}}.$$ In order to normalise this I take the integral, which due to the modulus on the $x$ I evaluate just from zero to infinity, giving $$\int_0^\infty |\psi(x,0)|^2dx=|N|^2\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{2x}{\lambda}}dx=|N|^2\Big[-\frac{\lambda}{2}e^{-\frac{2x}{\lambda}}\Big]_0^\infty=\frac{\lambda|N|^2}{2}=1.$$ Allowing a phase such that $|N|=N$ we get $$N=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\lambda}}.$$ However the solutions say $$N=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}}.$$ Where am I going wrong in my computation?

**Fourier transform**

I now want to calculate $c(k)$ from $$\psi(x,0)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty c(k)e^{ikx}dk,$$ so I compute $$c(k)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \psi(x,0)e^{-ikx}dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}}e^{-\frac{|x|}{\lambda}}e^{-ikx}dx.$$ I am struggling to integrate this. Do I again have to take a domain-splitting approach due to the modulus? I can't manage to get the correct result.

Comment: "In order to normalise this I take the integral, which due to the modulus on the $x$ I evaluate just from zero to infinity". Nope: you still have to integrate from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. Either that, or multiply by 2. Either way, you get that extra factor of 2. As for the second: yes: break the integral int two pieces, one over the negative x's and one over the positive. Then, you can get rid of the absolute values (for $x<0$, $|x| = -x$), combine the exponentials in the integrand, and from there it's a simple exponential integral.

Comment: OK thanks. So should there be a factor of two then? Also, integrating from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ results in either $1=0$ or $1=\infty$, or am I making a mistake somewhere?

Comment: For the integral along the negative x axis, integrate $e^{x/\lambda}$, because $|x| = -x$ if $x<0$.